# FiltersFeature multiple filters for a single column using "OR" logic via checkboxes/button outside of grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have successfully configured a grid panel using the FiltersFeature.js plugin. I am able to see the filter options in my column header menu item. I'm using strings, lists and date range types and only filtering locally, not remotely.

The behavior works as expected. For instance, I have a column of "Status" with a filter configured (via the config, not column) of:

```
filters: [{
  type: 'list',
  dataIndex: 'status',
  options: ['New', 'Waiting', 'Reopened','Working']
}]
```

Which correctly renders a list of checkboxes for each item of the options property. When I select both "New" AND "Working" from the list then the grid is filtered to show records matching status of "New" OR "Working".

Now, when I programatically add filters using something like:

```
tasksGrid.filters.addFilters([{type: 'string', dataIndex: 'status', value: 'New'}]);
tasksGrid.store.load();
```

It works to filter all the grid records to a matching status of "New".

The problem is I am unable to figure out how to add multiple parameters to the addFilters method in order to get the same built-in behavior of an "OR" search rather than an "AND" search.

When using the header menu selections and applying multiple filters to a single column I can see the filterData via the getFilterData() method is:

```
[Object
  data: Object
  type: "list"
  value: Array[2]
    0: "New"
    1: "Waiting"
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array[0]
  __proto__: Object
  field: "status"
  __proto__: Object
```

Where the value is set as an array of 2 values. However, when I try to do something like:

```
tasksGrid.filters.addFilters([{type: 'string', dataIndex: 'status', value: ['New','Waiting']}]);
```

I get the following result for filterData:

```
[Object
  data: Object
  type: "string"
  value: "New,Waiting"
  __proto__: Object
  field: "status"
  __proto__: Object
```

I figured it is concatenating the values because I used a type of string so I tried a type of 'list' which is what it is defined as in the filter config and I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined ... ListMenu.js:83

Any help would greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Seth

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused on what you are trying to do. If you just want to set the value of the filters, you can use this I believe:

```
tasksGrid.filters.getFilter('status').setValue(["New", "Waiting"]);
```

If you are trying to add the actual filter after the grid has been created, I looked at the doc for ux.ListFilter and ux.ListMenu and it doesn't look like you can create it with certain filters pre-selected. I'll have to dig a little more for the code to create a list filter.